# How to send JSON to RestAPI in talend?

Tags: json, rest, csv, talend

Hello Everyone,

I'm new to Talend just learning how to use the the components.

this is use case csv -> map -> json -> rest api

For the components, I implemented like this

tFileInputDelimited -> tMap -> tFileOutputJson ->RestClient

The output file produced as I expected.

now how to send the json content in the file to rest api as request?[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the json file, you can use `tWriteJSONFields` instead of `tFileOutputJSON`, which as an added bonus enables you to have more control over your json tree. Then you can do this:

```
tFileInputDelimited -- tMap -- tWriteJSONFields -- tMap -- tRESTClient
```

In `tWriteJSONFields` you define a column that will hold your json, and then in the `tMap` you map it to the column "string" which you inherit from `tRESTClient` (it has 2 predefined columns in its schema, body and string), you need to have the same schema on your tMap output as the input schema of `tRESTClient`.

Comment: How can you set a column name for the whole JSON? I can only do it for a sub element